# Border-radius on IOS 5 slows touch events

Tags: css, ios5

I'm working on an HTML5 application for iPhone and iPad. It uses touch events extensively. On an iPhone recently upgraded to iOS 5, if I include a border-radius value in my CSS, then touch events are seconds slower than if I remove the border-radius line. Weird, I know.

```
.item {
    background-color:none;
    padding:1px;
    color:#234;
    border: 1px white dotted; 
    cursor: default;
    text-align:middle;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this and found a fix other than to not use border-radius? The app up until the upgrade to iOS 5 worked fine. iPads are also slower, but not as noticeable - probably due to the faster processor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Common CSS Border Library](http://battletech.hopto.org/html_tutorials/rounded_css_borders/more_styles.html) instead to avoid the performance hit